# What are the accumulation points of ( $\pi,2\pi$ ] $\subset\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

I was just curious as to what the accumulation points of ( $\pi,2\pi$ ]  $\subset\mathbb{R}$ are. I had gotten $\pi,2\pi$,1.  But the other answers are 3 and 5.

Comment: can you include some workings how do you obtain those partial results?

Answer (score 1):

Every point in $[\pi, 2 \pi]$ is an accumulation point of $(\pi, 2\pi]$ since any neighbourhood of any point of in $[\pi, 2 \pi]$ contains a point of $(\pi, 2\pi]$.